# How to combine similar columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 possible delay categories for each gate. I am trying to find the Tot_Delay_Min at certain gates for each category, therefor I need to find a way to combine these Delay Categories into one Column and the total minutes for that category into another. DLY1MIN, DLY2MIN, and DLY3MIN correspond with DLY1CAT, DLY2CAT, and DLY3CAT.

This is a sample of what I have for one gate:

```
Gate     DLY1CAT     DLY1MIN      DLY2CAT      DLY2MIN     DLY3CAT     DLY3MIN
====     =======     =======      =======      =======     =======     =======
SDF      Weather     50           Fuel         3
SDF      Late Jet    10           Weather      9
SDF      Deice       9
SDF      Late Jet    7            Fuel         11
SDF      Computer    20           Weather      13
SDF      Load Issue  8            Deice        5           Fuel        3
SDF      Damage      20           Deice        7
```

This is a sample of what I would Like:

```
Gate     DLYCAT     DLYMIN
====     =======    =======
SDF      Weather    72
SDF      Deice      21
SDF      Computer   20
SDF      Damage     20
SDF      Fuel       17
SDF      Late Jet   17
SDF      Load Issue 8
```

Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: Where is the gate information on the second and subsequent rows?

Comment: Sorry thanks for the edit

Comment: Another example of why it's important to normalize databases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, and I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but this should work:

```
SELECT Gate, Category, SUM("Delay Minutes") AS "Delay Minutes"
FROM 
(
    SELECT  Gate AS Gate, 
        Dly1Cat AS Category,
        DLY1Min AS "Delay Minutes"
    FROM YourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  Gate AS Gate,
        Dly2Cat AS Category,
        DLY2MIN AS "Delay Minutes"
    FROM YourTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  Gate AS Gate,
        Dly3Cat AS Category,
        DLY3MIN AS "Delay Minutes"
    FROM YourTable
)
WHERE Category IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Gate, Category;
```

What you're doing here is making three separate queries for each of the categories - and then combining them via UNION ALL.  Then, you select from the combined result set and group by Gate and the newly created "Category" column.

EDIT:

Removed the groupings in the three inner queries since they are unneccessary.

SECOND EDIT:

Changed brackets to ticks since it's Oracle - thanks, a_horse_with_no_name

THIRD EDIT:

Only included quotes where needed.  Added semicolon to the end.  Removed table alias for Oracle compatibility.

Comment: I believe that you need to sum the delay minutes in your outer query as well?

Comment: Thanks, @TomH - Edited the answer.

Comment: `[Delay Minutes]` is an invalid identifier in SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's a column alias...Why would it be an invalid identifier?

Comment: Because `[` and `]` are not allowed in an identifier in (standard) SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it is - I use it all the time.  It's used to enclose a column name that has spaces in it.

Comment: try this in a new query window and see for yourself:  select test as [See it works!]

Comment: @StanShaw: it will not work in Oracle - which this question is about (or Postgres or Firebird or DB2 or MySQL or SAP Hana or or Teradata Vertica or HSQLDB or Informix and probably many others as well). See here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/6121

Comment: I removed the T. from the beginning of everything and the T at the end of the parenthesis in the first FROM. I added double quotes around every Category, Delay Minutes, and Gate. I added a semicolon at the end of the whole code and it ran beautifully. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and let me know if it is working or not.

```
    Select Gate, DLYCAT AS DLYCAT, SUM(DLYMIN) AS DLYMIN
FROM
(Select Gate, DLY1CAT AS DLYCAT, SUM(DLY1MIN) AS DLYMIN FROM [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] GROUP BY GATE, DLY1CAT
UNION ALL
Select Gate, DLY2CAT AS DLYCAT, SUM(DLY2MIN) AS DLYMIN FROM [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] GROUP BY GATE, DLY2CAT
UNION ALL
Select Gate, DLY3CAT AS DLYCAT, SUM(DLY3MIN) AS DLYMIN FROM [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] GROUP BY GATE, DLY3CAT) AS TEMP
WHERE DLYCAT IS NOT NULL AND DLYMIN IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GATE, DLYCAT
```

Comment: While he didn't include it in his post, I think it's safe to assume that there is more than one gate in his database, so you would need to include that in the groupings.

Comment: Also, selecting distinct is redundant when it's included in the group by clause.

Comment: `[ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1]` is an invalid identifier in SQL

Comment: Please check and let me know. I'm Sure, you are wrong.

Comment: @Mytroy2050 He is definitely wrong.  I'm not sure why, but he posted the same thing on my answer.  Perhaps he isn't familiar with aliased columns, but that would be really shocking for someone with as many points as he has.

Comment: @StanShaw: I am **not** wrong. Try the query in Oracle (or Postgres or Firebird or DB2 or many other databases) it will not work. And the question is tagged with `sql` (which refers to standard ANSI SQL) and Oracle. Neither one allows such an identifier

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the clarification.  I thought we were talking about SQL server.  Now I see the Oracle tag.  I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing this with only one aggregation and `union all` (or unpivot):

```
select gate, dlycat, sum(DLYMIN) as DLYMIN
from ((select Gate, DLY1CAT AS DLYCAT, DLY1MIN AS DLYMIN
       from [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] 
      ) union all
      (select Gate, DLY2CAT AS DLYCAT, DLY2MIN AS DLYMIN
       from [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] 
      ) union all
      (select Gate, DLY3CAT AS DLYCAT, DLY1MIN AS DLYMIN
       from [ExperimentalDatabase].[dbo].[Table_1] 
      )
     ) g
where dlycat is not null
group by gate, dlycat;
```

Comment: Nice, Gordon - I was glad to see you chime in here.  Is this all that can be done to improve my answer?  I was hoping there would be a slicker way of doing it, perhaps with cross apply.

Comment: @StanShaw . . . You can do it with `cross apply` as well.  That would actually be more efficient.